# https redirect not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Got a .htaccess file that is working correctly with the following

```
Redirect 301 /secure/test/ http://ww2.example.com/secure/test/
Redirect 301 /test/ http://ww2.example.com/test/
Redirect 301 /submission/ http://ww2.example.com/submission/
```

That will happily redirect:

```
http://example.com/secure/test/login.aspx
```

However if someone comes in on

```
https://example.com/secure/test/login.aspx
```

It doesn't work, how to I also redirect all https traffic to follow the rules above?

Comment: Is your `DocumentRoot` for `https` same as that of `http`?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your mod_alias redirects to use mod_rewrite instead.

For example, in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PROTOCOL} ^http(s?) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(secure/test/.*) http%1://ww2.example.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

This redirects `http` to `http` and `https` to `https`. (Are you sure you don't always want to redirect to `https` instead?)

The `%1` backreference matches the `s` in the `SERVER_PROTOCOL` (if present).

Clear your browser cache before testing (301 redirects are cached), and change the `302` (temporary) redirect to `301` (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK.